Axios keeps on calling 'onUploadProgress' although upload has finished
I have a super simple file upload functionality implemented with nextjs.
The files need to be uploaded vai presigned url to AWS S3.
The upload works fine but, showing the a progress by utilizing onUploadProgress results in a weird behaviour.
Although I receive a successful response from axios that the upload has been finished, it calls again onUploadProgressresulting in not deleting state.
This is the console output:
...trimmed    
Upload progress:  {loaded: 1998848, total: 2966497, progress: 0.6738075244977494, bytes: 32768, rate: 2943234, …}

Upload progress:  {loaded: 2113536, total: 2966497, progress: 0.7124686119689317, bytes: 114688, rate: 1992869, …}

Upload successful {data: '', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}

Upload progress:  {loaded: 2621440, total: 2966497, progress: 0.8836819993413106, bytes: 507904, rate: 1567905, …} # THIS IS THE WEIRD PART

Going to S3, I can see the the file was indeed successfully uploaded.
I really do not understand this behaviour. Any ideas?
Here is the code of my implementation.
"use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { File } from "buffer";
import React, { ChangeEvent, use, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { generatePresignedUploadUrl } from "../actions/s3";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import { toast } from "sonner";

const S3Upload = () => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number>(0);
  const [uploadCompleted, setUploadCompleted] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleFileChange = (e: any) => {
    setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  // Generate a presigned URL for the selected file
  const handlePresignedUrl = async () => {
    if (!selectedFile) {
      toast.error("Bitte wähle eine Datei aus!");
      return;
    }
    console.log("Uploading: ", selectedFile);

    const presignedUrl = await generatePresignedUploadUrl(
      selectedFile?.name as string
    );
    return presignedUrl;
  };

  // Function to upload the selected file using the generated presigned url
  const uploadToPresignedUrl = async () => {
    // Upload file to pre-signed URL;
    const url: string = (await handlePresignedUrl()) as string;

    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": selectedFile?.type,
        },

        onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent: any) {
          let percentCompleted = parseFloat(
            (progressEvent.progress * 100).toFixed(2)
          );

          console.log("Upload progress: ", progressEvent);
          setUploadProgress(percentCompleted);

          if (uploadProgress === 100) {
            setUploadCompleted(true);
          }
        },
      };
      const uploadResponse = await axios.put(url, selectedFile, config);

      // Check if the upload was successful
      if (uploadResponse.status === 200) {
        // setUploadProgress(100); // Set progress to 100% on successful upload
        // setUploadCompleted(true); // Mark upload as complete
        console.log("Upload successful", uploadResponse);
        toast.success("Video hochgeladen!");
      } else {
        toast.error("Fehler beim Hochladen des Videos!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading file: ", error);
      toast.error("Fehler beim Hochladen des Videos!");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // toast
    setUploadProgress(0);
    setSelectedFile(null);
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.value = "";
    }
  }, [uploadCompleted]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid w-full py-4 max-w-sm items-center gap-1.5">
        <Label htmlFor="aufzeichnung">Aufzeichnung</Label>
        <Input
          id="aufzeichnung"
          type="file"
          ref={inputRef}
          onChange={handleFileChange}
        />
        <Button
          disabled={uploadProgress > 0 && uploadProgress < 100}
          className="mt-2"
          onClick={uploadToPresignedUrl}
        >
          Upload
        </Button>
        <p>{uploadProgress > 0 ? `...${uploadProgress}%` : null} </p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default S3Upload;


